# Using modules for Python, from USB stick

Tags: python, import, module, usb

I need to be able to use a module/library for Python from a USB stick. I don't have root access to the computer (since it's in school) and I have very little disk space. My idea was to be able to have my Python program (e.g. for playing songs) and be able to use a library, such as [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/), to play those.

How can I import a pure library from a USB stick, into my program?

Comment: USB drives are not different than any other media. Of course on your school computers may be some restrictions.

Comment: I know that I can have a library on my USB, but how can I tell python to look for the library on the USB, instead of trying to find it in other places, where I can't place the files due to admin permissions.

Comment: Just append USB path to PYTHONPATH eviromental var before running your script. Or put your script on the USB drive itself.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I have quite a basic knowledge of Python and programming itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, to import modules you have to specify the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) if you want other paths to import your modules from.

Let's say you have modules in the path `path="/path/to/your/usb"` and you want to use them. Then, you should use

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/usb
$ python file.py
```

I.e., like Faust mentioned, USB drives are no different from other directories.